# Java ServerSocket to Tell Telnet Client to Send Every Character Immediately

Tags: java, sockets, telnet, serversocket

I'm attempting to capture an "up arrow" from clients connected to my socket where the client is using telnet to connect to my server. This would allow me to autofill command history of what the client user has used previously. In order to do this I need the client socket to send each character immediately rather than waiting for a CRLF.

However so far I'm only able to receive this data upon the user hitting the Enter key (and therefore sending a CRLF).

Is there a way to set something on the ServerSocket or the resulting Socket to tell the client to flush its output buffer on every single character typed? Just like it happens when you telnet/SSH to a server.

Comment: This actually has nothing to do with java or SocketServer, because such a generic class cannot handle this kind of specific task. What you should really be looking at is Telnet's RFC, or more specifically, [Telnet Linemode Option](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1116). That antiquity is too long for me to read in my spare time, so good luck :;

Comment: Thank you Glee8e.. I'll have a read. That does show some promise.